# php dynamic property accessor for nested properties

Tags: php

I can do:

```
$key = 'address';
$user->{$key}
```

Is there some way to make this work for deeper levels? I do not know in advance how many levels.

```
$key = 'address->street';
$user->{$key}
```

Here is what I am actually trying to achieve:

```
$filterIds = [];
$filterIds['facebook->followers'] = 1;
$filterIds['googleplus->followers'] = 2;
$filterIds['instagram->followers'] = 3;
...

    foreach($filterIds as $filterKey => $filterId) {
        if(self::property_path_exists($data, $filterKey)) {
            $filter = new ResultFilter;
            $filter->result_filter_id = $filterId;
            $filter->value = $data->{$filterKey};
            $filter->save();
        }
    }
```

Comment: is `'address->street'` how it would actually look in your source data.  If not, can how show how you're getting this data?

Comment: @PatrickQ yes the data would be $user->address->street

Comment: I understand that that's what you're trying to _produce_, but what is the actual _input_?  Where/how are you getting the value for `$key`?

Comment: @PatrickQ I have updated the question with an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example

```
<?php

$v = new stdClass;
$v->x = new stdClass;
$v->x->y = new stdClass;
$v->x->y->z = "wow";

$keys = "x->y->z";

$t = &$v;
foreach (explode("->", $keys) as $key) {
    // @TODO add isset($t->{$key})
    $t = &$t->{$key};
}

print($t . PHP_EOL);

$t = "changed";

print($v->x->y->z . PHP_EOL);
```

Remember to use reference (`&`) when you want to edit this nested object.